# @Query annotations in Spring Boot for elasticsearch to use Sort and Collapse

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a question like can we use @Query annotations in elasticsearch to act as a nested query to use Sort and Collapse.
my query looks like this::

```
GET clean/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix":{
      "search_term": "Monkey"
    }
  },

    "sort": [
      {
        "search_score": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      }
    ],
    "collapse":{
        "field": "normalized_term"
    },
    "size": 10
}
```

This is the query, can I implement using @Query annotations and how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'd need to use a `NativeSearchQuery` where you can set a sort and collapse. The `@Query` annotation on a method defines only the query part sent to Elasticsearch.